# 2 array find contains parametrs jquery

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays

```
 var a = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]];
 var b = [1,5,7];
```

And I need to find number of arrea in "a" which hasn't got intersections with "b"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It can be done in plain JavaScript simply using loop (`for`).

Comment: I need to find arrea in 'a' where no intersections with 'b'. I try to find number in list 'a' of [2,3].

Comment: What is an "arrea"? What is "its number"? Do you want to find all of them, or only the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var a = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]];
var b = [1, 5, 7];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    var intersect = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length && !intersect; j++)
    {
        for (var k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
        {
            if (b[k] == a[i][j])
            {
                intersect = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!intersect)
    {
        result.push(a[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmdguxb9/).

Comment: That doesn't look very simple…

Comment: @Bergi I mean simple for understanding, without any functions. But I'd better delete these words, yes.

Comment: Well, functional programming is typically simpler to understand. In Haskell it would be something like `let result = filter (not . intersects b) a`

Comment: @Bergi I had hard time writing first programs in Haskell :) But yes, your code looks more natural, even though it doesn't handle 2-dimensional array, does it?

Comment: It probably requires a definition of the `intersects` helper function. Edit: With the prelude, `intersects a b = not (null (intersect a b))` or so, or just `(not . intersects) a b = every (notElem a) b` :-)